# SPA route return 404 when called directly from address bar

Tags: angular, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a SPA with Angular (an angular project created with angular CLI, not the "templated one" of visual studio), and a .NET 6 web api project.

When I deploy the angular project's "compiled" files in the wwwroot folder of the web api project, and I run the application, everything works fine.

The problem is when I try to call the same url from the address bar, I get the http 404.

eg.
"https://localhost:5001/#/flower/list" reached by "home" works fine
"https://localhost:5001/#/flower/list" reached by address bar return http 404

Another thing that I don't understand is when I call http://localhost:5001 I get the http 404; I have to write http://localhost:5001/index.html for enter in the application.

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5189",
      "sslPort": 44343
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "UGIV.BE": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "index.html",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    
    var devCorsPolicy = "devCorsPolicy";
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(devCorsPolicy, builder => {        
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();        
        });
    });
    
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseCors(devCorsPolicy);
    }
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { CommonGuard } from './guards/common.guard';
    import { FlowerDetailsComponent } from './flower-details/flower-details.component';
    import { FlowerListComponent } from './flower-list/flower-list.component';
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      {path:'', redirectTo: 'flower/list', pathMatch:'full'},
      { 
        path:'flower', canActivate:[CommonGuard], children:[
          {path: 'flower', component: FlowerListComponent },
          {path: 'flower-details/:id',component: FlowerDetailsComponent }
      ] 
      
      },
      
      
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your frustration is this line you set here:

```
  {path:'', redirectTo: 'flower/list', pathMatch:'full'},
```

You are asking Angular to redirect to a route called `flower/list` while it does not exist in your list of open routes. So it is a normal output.

I can list to you all the steps you have to follow to get a seamless experience when it comes to routing. But this is not convenient since Angular Documentation already illustrates this very well in a dedicated part in the Official website call [Common Routing Tasks](https://angular.io/guide/router). Read there on how to set a default route, set a wild card (for routes that users may enter while the application routing system does not support) and much more...